# ws-rs: E0271r: expected (), found enum `std::result::Result`

Tags: enums, websocket, rust, fibonacci

I'm learning Rust, and I'm attempting to make a WebSocket server that calculates the Fibonacci for n and sends the result back. I'm getting the error:

```
 expected (), found enum `std::result::Result`
```

Here is my code (with comments):

```
extern crate ws;// add websocket crate
extern crate num;// add num crate (to handle big numbers)
extern crate regex;// regex crate

use ws::listen;
use num::bigint::BigUint;
use num::traits::{Zero, One};
use std::env;
use std::mem::replace;// used to swap variables

fn main() {
    let re = regex::Regex::new("[0-9]+").unwrap();// regex to check if msg is a number.
    listen("0.0.0.0:8080", |conn| {// this is where the arrows in the error message points to
        move |msg| {
            if re.is_match(msg) {// check if message matches the regex
                let num: i64 = msg.parse().unwrap();// set num to the msg as an integer
                conn.send(ws::Message::Text(fib(num).to_string()));// create a new ws message with the Fib of num
            }
        }
    }).unwrap();
}

fn fib(n: i64) -> BigUint {// fibonacci function
    let mut f0 = Zero::zero();
    let mut f1 = One::one();
    for _ in 0..n {
        let f2 = f0 + &f1;
        f0 = replace(&mut f1, f2);
    }
    f0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that was a *very* confusing compiler error. Consider filing a bug. ;)
Please see my comments describing the fix.

```rust
fn main() {
    listen("0.0.0.0:8080", |conn| {
        // Needs to return a `Result` on all code paths.
        // You were missing an `else`.
        move |msg: ws::Message| {
            // Need to extract text before parsing.
            let text = msg.into_text().unwrap();
            // Don't need regex -- parse and check success.
            match text.parse() {
                Ok(num) => conn.send(ws::Message::Text(fib(num).to_string())),
                Err(err) => Ok(()), // Or return an error if you prefer.
            }
        }
    }).unwrap();
}
```

Further details:

- [listen()](https://docs.rs/ws/0.7.3/ws/fn.listen.html) must return something that implements `Handler`.
- [Handler](https://docs.rs/ws/0.7.3/ws/trait.Handler.html) is implemented for  all `F: Fn(Message) -> Result<()>`. So your method needs to return a `Result<()>` on all code paths.
- Conceptually, `Handler` could be implemented for something else as well. The compiler is not able to infer the type of `msg` as it's not being directly passed into a method with a known type signature; so the compiler can't infer its type and we need to provide it explicitly.